# How to rank values in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I would like to create a ranking of observations using SPARQL. Suppose I have:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org#> .

:A :value 60 .
:B :value 23 .
:C :value 89 .
:D :value 34 .
```

The ranking should be: :C = 1 (the highest), :A = 2, :D = 3, :B = 4.  Up until now, I was able solve it using the following query:

```sql
prefix : <http://example.org#> 
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT ?x ?v ?ranking { 
 ?x :value ?v .
 { SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(?x;separator="") as ?ordered) {
    { SELECT ?x {
       ?x :value ?v .
      } ORDER BY DESC(?v)
    }
   }
 }
 BIND (str(?x) as ?xName)
 BIND (strbefore(?ordered,?xName) as ?before) 
 BIND ((strlen(?before) / strlen(?xName)) + 1 as ?ranking)
} ORDER BY ?ranking
```

But that query only works if the URIs for `?x` have the same length.  A better solution would be to have a function similar to `strpos` in PHP or `isIndexOf` in Java, but as far as I know, they are not available in SPARQL 1.1.  Are there simpler solutions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is that you want to create?  Or show what the query that you wrote produces? The inner select query already orders the results, so you can already have them ordered.  The outer queries do a bunch of string manipulation, and seeing an example of what they're producing would help a lot.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're asking for, you want the results to be, e.g., `C 89 1; A 60 2; D 34 3; B 23 4`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing this is to take as the ranking for a value the number of values which are less than or equal to it. This might be inefficient for larger data sets, since for each value it has to check all the other values.  It doesn't require string manipulation though.

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.org#>

SELECT ?x ?v (COUNT(*) as ?ranking) WHERE {
  ?x :value ?v .
  [] :value ?u .
  FILTER( ?v <= ?u )
}
GROUP BY ?x ?v
ORDER BY ?ranking
```

```
---------------------
| x  | v  | ranking |
=====================
| :C | 89 | 1       |
| :A | 60 | 2       |
| :D | 34 | 3       |
| :B | 23 | 4       |
---------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a different solution than the one I proposed, although as you say, I am not sure if it will be very efficient for large datasets. Although my example was short, my real application can have around 100 observations and using your approach it means 100 subqueries. Anyway, once I have my full dataset prepared, I will compare your soluton to the one I wrote above.

Comment: @Labra I just generated some more sample data, and on 1000 elements, my answer takes about 4.5 seconds, while your original answer takes about 2.5­–2.8.  With just 100 elements, the difference is smaller, my answer takes about 1.8 seconds, yours takes 1.5.

Comment: @Labra In terms of reusability though, I will point out that after the first time I generated sample data, your query gave some strange results.  It took me a while to remember that yours requires that all the resources have URIs whose string forms are the same length.   I had to adapt the data generator to make sure that that was the case.

Comment: OK, great! Well, in my particular problem, the resources are URIs of countries identified by their 3 letter iso code, so I know they have the same length :).  But as you say, your solution is more general and can be applied to any case. Nevertheless, I was surprised that this seemingly easy question was so difficult to express in SPARQL...

Comment: @Labra Well, I don't know the solution I provided is necessarily “so difficult”;  it's just that when you can take advantage of a particular property of your data (e.g.,  IRIs have the same length), the solution that takes advantage of the _optimization_ is a bit more complex.  Something like `strpos` would definitely be handy, of course.  Are you using an endpoint that you control?  Adding an extension to it might not be all that hard…

Comment: No, I have no endpoint under my control. I am defining the SPARQL queries as a means to validate RDF data, so I am trying to avoid extensions as much as I can. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer. I will probably use it, although as you say, it would be better to have more builtin functions like strpos...

Comment: @Labra Did you end up using this?  If so, you might consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437). (Though by all means, if you're hoping that a better solution appears, don't accept;  we don't want to discourage getting more answers!)  If you didn't use this, and ended up doing something else, can you post it an answer (and you could accept that, too) so that others can benefit, too?

Comment: I accepted it, although asyou say, in my opinion there should be a more efficient way to do it. Butas far as it seems the only way by now, you are right that it should be accepted. As a side note, in my system, I ended up programming that query using Jena's API.