# Aggregation + Rank in SPARQL -> Cumulative Percent?

Tags: sparql, aggregation, rank

A very elegant way to compute ranking into SPARQL has beeen suggested by Joshua Taylor in the answer to the following question
[How to rank values in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313730/how-to-rank-values-in-sparql)

However, I need the Aggregation + Ranking as a first step to obtain the cumulative percent in queries such as "Countries that account for top 50% of the sales amount."

Suppose that we have sales at state level

```
California 30
Arizona 25
...
Alberta 25
Quebec 20
...
```

I would need to first aggregate by country and obtain the rank of the country as follows

```
United States 250 1
Canada 200 2
Mexico 150 3
...
```

How to write Aggregation + Rank in SPARQL generalizing Joshua's answer mentioned above ?

For the next step I would need to do the cumulative sum using the rank as follows

```
United States 250 1 250
Canada 200 2 450
Mexico 150 3 600
...
```

For writing this in SPARQL I guess I can use a SQL trick as reported here
[how to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

If the above succeeded, then we can try the cumulative percentage. Suppose now that the total sales for all countries is 1000. Then the result would be

```
United States 250  250
Canada 200 450
```

For writing this in SPARQL we can use something that in SQL would be like follows

```
SELECT CountryName, SalesAmount
FROM CumSalesCountry
WHERE CumSalesAmount <=
(SELECT MIN(CumSalesAmount) FROM CumSalesCountry
WHERE CumSalesAmount >=
(SELECT 0.5 * SUM(SalesAmount) FROM SalesCountry) ) )
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Esteban (struggling with writing BI-like queries in SPARQL ...)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you've got data like this:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:a1 a :A ; :v 05 .
:a2 a :A ; :v 10 .

:b1 a :B ; :v 10 .
:b2 a :B ; :v 10 .
:b3 a :B ; :v 05 .

:c1 a :C ; :v 10 .
```

Then you can use a query like this:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select
   ?type
   (?value*100/?total as ?percent)
   (count(?type2) as ?rank)
   (sum(?value2)*100/?total as ?cumulativePercent)
where { 
  #-- total value across all types 
  { select (sum(?value) as ?total) 
    where { ?x :v ?value } }

  #-- each type and its sum value as ?type and ?value
  { select ?type (sum(?v) as ?value)
    where { ?x a ?type ; :v ?v }
    group by ?type }

  #-- each type and its sum value as ?type2 and ?value2
  { select ?type2 (sum(?v) as ?value2)
    where { ?x a ?type2 ; :v ?v }
    group by ?type2 }

  filter ( ?value2 >= ?value )
}
group by ?type ?value ?total
order by desc(?percent)
```

to get results like these:

```
---------------------------------------------
| type | percent | rank | cumulativePercent |
=============================================
| :B   | 50.0    | 1    | 50.0              |
| :A   | 30.0    | 2    | 80.0              |
| :C   | 20.0    | 3    | 100.0             |
---------------------------------------------
```

Now, there is a problem here, if tow of the types have the same
percentages.  E.g., if you add the data

```
:d1 a :D ; :v 07 .
:d2 a :D ; :v 08 .
```

then you get the results:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| type | percent                     | rank | cumulativePercent           |
===========================================================================
| :B   | 38.461538461538461538461538 | 1    | 38.461538461538461538461538 |
| :A   | 23.076923076923076923076923 | 3    | 84.615384615384615384615384 |
| :D   | 23.076923076923076923076923 | 3    | 84.615384615384615384615384 |
| :C   | 15.384615384615384615384615 | 4    | 99.999999999999999999999999 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That shows that A and D are tied, and gives them the same cumulative
percentage and rank.  If that's not what you want, you can add
something to the filter condition, e.g.,

```sql
filter (  ?value2 > ?value
       || ( ?value2 = ?value &&
            str(?type2) >= str(?type) ))
```

to resolve the identical cases and get results like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| type | percent                     | rank | cumulativePercent           |
===========================================================================
| :B   | 38.461538461538461538461538 | 1    | 38.461538461538461538461538 |
| :D   | 23.076923076923076923076923 | 2    | 61.538461538461538461538461 |
| :A   | 23.076923076923076923076923 | 3    | 84.615384615384615384615384 |
| :C   | 15.384615384615384615384615 | 4    | 99.999999999999999999999999 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL support subqueries which can be used for calculation of aggregates as part of an overall query:

```
SELECT * {
  { SELECT (MIN(?CumSalesAmount) AS ?minSalesAmount) 
    {  ... get ?CumSalesAmount ... } }
  { SELECT (0.5*sum(?SalesAmount) AS ?aggSalesAmount) 
     {  ... get ?SalesAmount ... } }
  ... get ?CountryName ?SalesAmount ...
}
```

The effects are not identical - it's a way of approaching the problem, not a translation clone of your example.