# SPARQL ranking on two predicates

Tags: sparql, rdf

Is it possible to create a SPARQL query that produces a result with the ranking based on two predicates? I have searched for similar queries the closest solution I could find is given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313730/how-to-rank-values-in-sparql). That solution gave me a timeout since I have about 600 triples so an efficient solution will be greatly appreciated. Consider the RDF below:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org#> .

:A :groupid 119;
   :date 2018-04-01.
:B :groupid 119 ;
   :date 2018-03-01.
:C :groupid 119 ;
   :date 2018-05-01.
:D :groupid 120  ;
   :date 2018-02-01.
:E :groupid 120 ;  
   :date 2018-03-01.
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
| id   |   date     |ranking  |
==============================
| 119  | 2018-03-01 | 1       |
| 119  | 2018-04-01 | 2       |
| 119  | 2018-05-01 | 3       |
| 120  | 2018-02-01 | 1       |
| 120  | 2018-03-01 | 2       |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: `PREFIX : <http://example.org#>
SELECT ?id ?date (COUNT(*) as ?ranking) WHERE {
  ?x :groupid ?id ;
     :date ?date .
  ?y :groupid ?id ;
     :date ?date2 .
  filter(?date2 <= ?date)
  
}
GROUP BY ?id ?date
ORDER BY ?id ?date ?ranking`

Answer (score 0):

As answered by AKSW, this script works perfectly:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org#> 
SELECT ?id ?date (COUNT(*) as ?ranking)
{
   ?x :groupid ?id ; :date ?date .
   ?y :groupid ?id ; :date ?date2 .
    filter(?date2 <= ?date) 
}
GROUP BY ?id ?date
ORDER BY ?id ?date ?ranking
```